# Angular: How can I use the same view (For example Home) differentiating through an id?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a page (Home) where its main content will be consumed by different people, the variations for each person would be separated by an id

localhost:4200/?number=10

localhost:4200/?number=20

These IDs would be taken from this API for example:

```
{
  "teste": [
    {
      "id":"1",
      "number":"10",
      "nome":"Test-Two",
   },
   {
    "id":"2",
    "number":"20",
    "name":"Test-One",
 }
  ]
}
```

Could anyone give me a suggestion on how I can do it?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but maybe simple example from angular doc could help here? https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 - in half of the page you will find detail/:id path for routing from hero list to hero details page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ActivatedRoute to access the parameters in url.

Import it:

`import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

Add to constructor:

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}`

And in, for example, `onInit()`:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if(params['number']){
        let whatever = params['number'];
        // do your thing with whatever, for example:
        // use it to find the index of its object
        // inside `teste` to retrieve other keys/values
    }
});
```